Repeat last navigation command
Is there a way to repeat my last navigation command like 10k or 7j or similar. I can use Ctrl + u or Ctrl + d but I like something like ; or ,.

Welcome to [vi.se]!

I'm not aware of any standard way to repeat motions.
But there are two plugins that have been developed to fill that gap:

repmo-vim
vim-remotions

I'm the author of the second that I have developed to be able to repeat filetype specific motions like ]m, ]M (see: difference with repmo-vim)
It allows you to list the motions that you would to repeat with the ;, , keys (see: remotions introduction)
